Using Configuration Properties in static function
I have a Spring Boot application and want to call static function in my @Services which uses Configuration Properties. Say, I have a property class
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "connection")
public class ConnectConfig {
    private String useragent;
    private String referrer;
}

and a function
public class MyUtils {
    public static Document connect(String url) throws IOException {
        return Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("ConnectConfig.useragent").referrer("ConnectConfig.referrer").execute().parse();
    }
}

How can I have property values there?

You can create a config class and in the PostContruct() method of the same class, you can call your static method (MyUtils.connect()) to load the properties. In this way, properties will get loaded at the start of the application only.

No, my method does not load properties and is not a bean method. It is static like Math.min. I just want to get the configuration file setting value inside it.

In the Configuration file, you can create one method and then return one POJO after setting the properties value from the same. You need to annotate the method with Qualifier and Bean. Then in MyUtils, you can just autowire the same method with Qualifier annotation. In this way you will get returned POJO from configuration class to your MyUtils class.
